# MongoDB + WiredTiger cache usage stuck on 95%

Tags: mongodb, cache, mongodb-3.4, wiredtiger

I'm running a mongo 3.4.7 cluster (8 CPU, 120GB ram, primary + 2 secondaries) with ±130 open connections, each one of them to a separate DB with ±50 collections.

After a few minutes of running, cache usage percent goes to 95% and stays there. Sometimes is goes down a bit to ±93%, but quickly returns to 95%.

According to the [docs](http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.9.0/tune_cache.html), when cache usage is at 95%, WiredTiger will start using application threads for eviction, which slows down the DB and can explain why cache usage doesn't get higher than 95%.

What is the reason that cache eviction can't keep up with the load, while machine resources are under-utilized (CPU, Disk)?

Tried increasing the number of eviction threads to the maximum of 20, no luck there.

**Update:**

Here are the result of `iostat -myx 1`

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          15.40    0.00    0.63    0.00    0.13   83.84

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvde              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdc              0.00     9.00  166.00   22.00     2.27     0.17    26.52     0.14    0.74    0.51    2.55   0.40   7.60
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: And you know for sure that your disk IO is not your bottleneck? It sounds like that data store doesn't have high enough IOPS rate. What `sudo iostat -myx 1` says for data disk %util and overall %iowait.

Comment: @JJussi i've updated the question with the results, doesn't look like there's a bottleneck there

Comment: Yes, write to disk is almost non-existent and read is low too. So, if there was high query load same time (when that iostat was taken), your applications are querying documents what are in cache --> cache usage is high and it's hard to evict information back to the disks. Probably you don't have slow queries logged in mongod.log?

Comment: @Tzach It might help if you post your deployment details. Are you using one machine per `mongod` or one machine for all three `mongod`, and are you doing a heavy insert workload? Could you also post the output of the `mongostat` tool, `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` from the `mongo` shell? Also, there is a known cache eviction issue with a certain workload that was fixed in MongoDB 3.4.9: see [WT-3329](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-3329). Maybe upgrading to 3.4.9 could help in your case?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha wow I wasn't aware of this bug, thank you! Will give 3.4.9 a try and update here.